# How to use the appropriate encoding when reading csv in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, utf-8

I am trying to load datasets from FDIC. Every quarter FDIC releases a zip file that contains around 62 csv files with names like the following:

```
All_Reports_20080331_Assets and Liabilities.cvs,
All_Reports_20080331_Bank Assets Sold and Securitized.csv, 
etc
```

I have downloaded the all the files in a directory like the following:

```
C:\projects\FDIC\All_Reports_20080331
```

Once there are many zip files, from different quarters available, I am starting to prepare a structure for a loop that will run over many paths (each one representing a quarter with 62 csv files inside). Before getting into the loop, however, the upload is not working due to some utf_8 error.

```
import pandas as pd
path = r"C:\projects\FDIC\All_Reports_20080331"
file = r"\All_Reports_20080331_Assets and Liabilities.csv"
df_assets_&_liab = pd.read_csv(path+file)
```

gives me the following error:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 5: invalid start byte
```

I tried to use a  parameter in pandas.read_csv to "utf_8" but error message is the same.

Any idea on how to better load those files via panda? 
Thanks a lot!

ps: the forder with the 62 csv files can be found here: [FDIC Website](https://www5.fdic.gov/sdi/download_large_list_outside.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look at the encoding format of the file.

```
import chardet
with open(path+file,"rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
    print(chardet.detect(data))

{'encoding': 'ISO-8859-1', 'confidence': 0.73, 'language': ''}
```

Then

```
df_assets_&_liab = pd.read_csv(path+file,encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, Yugang. Curiously It took 4 min to run over a 5 mb file. Thank you very much for such a answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Guga Yes,it is slow as you say. You can also try `cchardet ` that is high speed universal character encoding detector.

Comment: Does my question deserve a + ? Or was it too stupid ? :-)